# How the period of @Scheduled cron will be measured?

Tags: java, spring, cron, spring-scheduled

I need to describe how the [@Scheduled](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html) annotation works.
There are three definition for Scheduled: *fixedDelay*, *fixedRate* and *cron*.
While the period of *fixedDelay* will be measured from the completion time of each preceding invocation, the period of *fixedRate* will be measured between the successive start times of each invocation.

But what about the *cron* period? How he will be measured?

**Edit**:
I know *cron* is not a period like the both *fixed*-information. I will describe my question with an example.

An example-method need 2 minutes to be finished. But with the *@Scheduled*-Annotation, I will let the method run every minute.

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1000)
public void exampleMethod(){}
```

fixedDelay will wait until the method is completed, and then he wait one minute. So the method will run every 3 Minutes.

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 1000)
public void exampleMethod(){}
```

fixedRate will wait one minute between the successive start times of each invocation. So the method will run every minute, doesn't matter if the method is completed or not.

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 * * * * *")
public void exampleMethod(){}
```

So I set the cron to run every minute. Will the method be executed every minute or will cron wait until the method is completed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cron is a format that describes when a job should run. You can see a lot of good examples [here](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/crontrigger)

Comment: I know how to use cron. But if I say, the method should run each minute, but the method needs more than one minute to be finished, does the Scheduled-annotation wait 'till the invocation is ended?

Comment: That totally depends on how many threads you have allocated for the scheduler thread pool. If you have only one, then each task will block each next one.

Answer (score 0):

Cron is not perod, a format similar records indicate periodicity in Linux scheduler [Cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

Comment: I know cron. Please take a look to my edit, where I tried to explain my question better.